# how to serve assets from Nest.js and add middleware to detect image request

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I am trying to serve image from Nest.js server and add middleware to track all request but the only way I could make it work was with express

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import {AppModule} from "./app.module";
import * as path from "path";
import * as express from 'express';


async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));

  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    next();
  });
  //
  app.use('/api/track/',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))); //Serves resources from public folder
  app.use('/api/track/:img', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('do something');
    next();
  });

  await app.listen(3333);
}

bootstrap();
```

How can I implement it with using the controller or middleware?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[The nestjs doc tells you, how to serve static files.](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc) In short, here is how you do it:

Specify root directory of your assets in you main.ts

```
app.useStaticAssets(path.join(__dirname, '/../public'));
```

Use the @Res annotation to be able to use the sendFile method of express framework

```
@Get('track/:imgId')
test(@Param('imgId') imgId, @Res() res) {
  const imgPath = getImgPath(imgId);
  return res.sendFile(imgPath, { root: 'public' });
}
```

This solution assumes that your nestjs installation uses express under the hood.

---

Sources:

- https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/402
- https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc

Want to add a point here, please make sure you're using:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
```

Instead of this:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
```

in your `main.ts` file.

Comment: Where getImgPath comes from?

Comment: @DiegoSarmiento e.g. you store the path (or link) to the image in the database and getImgPath retrieves that path by imgId.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. Just inject this controller in app module.

```
import { Controller, Get, Req, Res } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('uploads')
export class ServeFilesController {
    @Get('products/images/:imageName')
    invoke(@Req() req, @Res() res) {
        return res.sendFile(req.path, { root: './' });
    }
}
```